# Cargo test keeps failing on github actions but passes on local machine

Tags: rust, github-actions, rust-cargo

Unit-tests are giving this error:

```
/home/runner/.cargo/bin/cargo unit-test --locked
    Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/enigmampc/SecretNetwork`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/Haseeb30000/secret-toolkit`
 Downloading crates ...
  Downloaded rand_chacha v0.2.2
.....
.....
  Downloaded rust_decimal v1.25.0
error: failed to parse manifest at `/home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rust_decimal-1.25.0/Cargo.toml`
Error: failed to parse manifest at `/home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rust_decimal-1.25.0/Cargo.toml`
Caused by:
  failed to parse the `edition` key
Caused by:
  this version of Cargo is older than the `2021` edition, and only supports `2015` and `2018` editions.
Error: The process '/home/runner/.cargo/bin/cargo' failed with exit code 101
```

I keep changed the version of rust_decimal to v-1.25.0 but it still gives error.
Here's cargo.toml

```
[package]

name = "pool_party"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

exclude = [
  # Those files are rust-optimizer artifacts. You might want to commit them for convenience but they should not be part of the source code publication.
  "contract.wasm",
  "hash.txt",
]

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[profile.release]
opt-level = 3
debug = false
rpath = false
lto = true
debug-assertions = false
codegen-units = 1
panic = 'abort'
incremental = false
overflow-checks = true

[features]
# for quicker tests, cargo test --lib
# for more explicit tests, cargo test --features=backtraces
backtraces = ["cosmwasm-std/backtraces"]

[dependencies]
cosmwasm-std = { git = "https://github.com/enigmampc/SecretNetwork", tag = "v1.0.0", features = ["staking"] }
cosmwasm-storage = { git = "https://github.com/enigmampc/SecretNetwork", tag = "v1.0.0" }
secret-toolkit = { git = "https://github.com/Haseeb30000/secret-toolkit",  branch = "master" }


schemars = "0.7"
serde = { version = "1.0.103", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.1"
snafu = { version = "0.6.3" }
bincode2 = "2.0.1"
subtle = { version = "2.2.3", default-features = false }
base64 = "0.12.3"
hex = "0.4.2"
rust_decimal = { version = "1.25.0", default-features = false}

rand_chacha = { version = "0.2.2", default-features = false }
#rand_core = { version =  "0.5.1", default-features = false }
rand = { version = "0.7.3" }
sha2 = { version = "0.9.1", default-features = false }

[dev-dependencies]
cosmwasm-schema = { version = "0.10.0" }
```

All `cargo build` and `cargo unit-test` works just fine.
cargo test passes on my local macbook pro (M1) but fails on github actions with the error

Here the .yaml

```
# Based on https://github.com/actions-rs/example/blob/master/.github/workflows/quickstart.yml

on: [push, pull_request]

name: Basic

jobs:

  test:
    name: Test Suite
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install stable toolchain
        uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          profile: minimal
          toolchain: 1.46.0
          target: wasm32-unknown-unknown
          override: true

      - name: Run unit tests
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: unit-test
          args: --locked
        env:
          RUST_BACKTRACE: 1

      - name: Compile WASM contract
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: wasm
          args: --locked
        env:
          RUSTFLAGS: "-C link-arg=-s"

      - name: Run integration tests
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: integration-test
          args: --locked


  lints:
    name: Lints
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install stable toolchain
        uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          profile: minimal
          toolchain: 1.46.0
          override: true
          components: rustfmt, clippy

      - name: Run cargo fmt
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: fmt
          args: --all -- --check

      - name: Run cargo clippy
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: clippy
          args: -- -D warnings

      # TODO: we should check
      # CHANGES_IN_REPO=$(git status --porcelain)
      # after this, but I don't know how
      - name: Generate Schema
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: schema
          args: --locked
```

The cargo test is failing with a `failed with exit code 101`. I have changed from rust_decimal=1.17.0 to rust_decimal=1.25.0 but it still fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using too old version on CI (1.46.0). Update it to use more recent version that supports the 2021 edition:

```yaml
jobs:

  test:
    name: Test Suite
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install stable toolchain
        uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          profile: minimal
          toolchain: 1.62.0
          target: wasm32-unknown-unknown
          override: true

...

  lints:
    name: Lints
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install stable toolchain
        uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          profile: minimal
          toolchain: 1.62.0
          override: true
          components: rustfmt, clippy
...
```